# Is it possible to add a image in JFrame but the class is extended with JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code, i can run it in class extended with JFrame. But now i need to add this code to a class extended with JPanel. Is it possible to add this in JPanel class? If cannot how can i add an image in JPanel class?

```
  JLabel img; 
  String url = "image/Screenshot(295).png";  

  void Car() {
     
      frame=new JFrame("Malaysia Checker");
      frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
      img = new JLabel();     
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url); 
      img.setIcon(icon);  
      img.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);           
      add(img);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(500,500);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Yes, and you should.  A `JPanel` is just a type of container, which is the same as you get from `JFrame#getContentPane`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, yes, and you should.  A `JPanel` is just a type of container, a `JFrame` is a specialised type of container, so many of the concepts are transferable.

[image: Simple]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            try {
                // Warning, this is a blocking call and my slow down the launch/presentation of the view
                BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/30/Java_programming_language_logo.svg/234px-Java_programming_language_logo.svg.png"));
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(background));
                add(label);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                add(new JLabel("Could not load background image"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Remember, in order to display any component, you need some kind of `Window` class, here I've just used a `JFrame` as the top level container

This kind of question would be better answer by reading through the [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) tutorials

Comment: Now i had display a Jframe in jpanel class. However , i cannot add any text or image into there. Actually i need click the button and the system should jump out a jframe with a picture

Comment: *"Now i had display a Jframe in jpanel class"* makes no sense, that's not how the system work - a `JFrame` is a top level container, it's responsible for displaying other components, not the other way around